# Is a non empty set (not containing $\emptyset$) and its power set disjoint?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Or do there exist sets $x,y\neq \emptyset$ so that $x\in y$ and $x\subseteq y$? I think that such sets do not exist and tried to prove it using the regularity axiom as in another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460166/does-there-exist-a-non-empty-set-that-is-a-subset-of-its-power-set); this does not seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: There are sets $y$ such that $x \in y$ implies that $x\subset y$. Such a set is by definition *transitive*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider the case where both $x$ and $\{x\}$ are elements of $y$.

Comment: You finished typing first :)  I guess a hint is better than an outright solution.

Comment: @Ryan: I was writing it from my cellphone, from bed, but it died so I figured it's time to get up. If that hadn't had happened my answer would have been posted two minutes earlier. ;-)

Comment: Simpler than I thought. Oh well, thanks Asaf.